# What makes EACCES on Android?

Tags: android

I know that this question is too abstract. So to make things more concrete, I'm examining on dirtycow(CVE-2016-5195). And especially for Android(6.0), I confirmed this [PoC](https://github.com/timwr/CVE-2016-5195) works and modified [run-as.c](https://github.com/timwr/CVE-2016-5195/blob/master/run-as.c) to show `whoami`

```
char *whoami[]= { "/system/bin/whoami", 0 };
execve(whoami[0], whoami, 0);
```

, which shows `root`. But even if I modified the code to exec shell(/system/bin/sh). The code is rejected with EACCES. What is the missing point?! The SE Linux or the other Linux security policy I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Yes, definitely SELinux.

Answer (score -1):

**EACCES** on Android means you don't have sufficient privileges to access whatever medium (**internal storage or external storage**)you are trying to access.This may arise even when you don't declare the right permissions in manifest file.

Comment: True, but irrelevant.